# DDR3L and microprocesor tracing

Tags: ddr3

I have a new project with DDR3L [MT41K128M16JT-125 IT](https://www.micron.com/products/dram/ddr3-sdram/part-catalog/mt41k128m16jt-125-it) and [Rockchip 3308](https://www.rock-chips.com/a/en/products/RK33_Series/2018/0614/907.html). This is my first time with DDR3L and microprocessor tracing. So I have few questions.

1. Can I tracing DQ[7:0] + (UDQS# and UDQS) and DQ[15:8] + (LDQS# + LDQS) on different layers? All tracks should be same length and (UDQS# + UDQS and LDQS# + LDQS) as differential pair. What is min and max length?
2. Can I tracing CK and CK# as differential pair on different layer? What is min and max length?
3. Can I tracing A13, A12/BC#, A11, A10/AP, A[9:0] on different layer? Should it be the same length? What is min and max length?
4. Can I tracing BA[2:0], CKE, CS#, RESET# and ect on different layer? Should it be the same length? What is min and max length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would avoid different layers for length-matched signals, because they are not actually length- but runtime-matched, and internal layers have different propagation speed.
2. The same applies to differential pairs -- these should be on layers with the same propagation properties.
3. The A lines belong to the A/C group.
4. The BA/CKE/CS/RESET lines belong to the A/C group.

The A/C group uses the CK clock and needs to be length-matched to the CK signal.

The DQ groups use DQS as the clock and need to be length-matched to the DQS signal.

The A/C group needs to be longer than the DQ groups. If your controller supports write leveling, you have a lot of freedom there, if it doesn't, the DQ groups should follow the length of the A/C group to the respective IC (but be shorter than A/C still).

For an x16 interface with UDQS and LDQS I'd treat those as two independent x8 interfaces.

You can put a single group on a separate layer together, as long as the constraints between groups are still met. Multiply the length with the difference in propagation speed to see if they are.